# How to proxy a preflight request with status OK using Go?

Tags: go

Given a client making a HTTP request

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/messages', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ data: 'foo' })
            })
            .then(async response => {
                console.log(await response.json());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The API server does not handle the request, the request handler should act as a proxy and send the request to another server

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/messages", handleRequest)

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", mux)
}

func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

    targetUrl, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:3001/messages")

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(targetUrl)
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

The target server should handle the request and send back the response

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/messages", handleRequest)

    http.ListenAndServe(":3001", mux)
}

func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("bar")
}
```

I start both servers and run the .html file, I would expect a

> bar

in the console. But unfortunately I get the error

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/messages' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

[image]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Instead of manually re-implementing CORS (which is error-prone), you should use a proven middleware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a different path for handling preflight requests in your proxy.
this is how your proxy should look like:

```
func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        return
    }
    targetUrl, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:3001")

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(targetUrl)
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Notice the changes:

1. `OPTION` requests(preflights) are not passed to server, you just accept them by sending a `OK` status.
2. (irrelevant to CORS problem) target url should not have `/message` part. path part is already present in your request, you should not repeat it.

Also you need to change the server code and remove these headers:

```
// w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
// w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
// w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
```

They are already set by the proxy. Server doesn't respond to the web-browser anymore.

Comment: Careful: not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests.